# How to read a currency symbol from an xlsx file in python using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I have an `.xlsx` file that contains the salary information of international workforce of an organization. I'm extracting some of the their details. All goes fine except for their salaries.

The salary values look like: `£10,000` or `€34000` and etc. In the excel file, the symbol was added via the Format Cell option. But my code reads only the actual numbers without the currency symbol.

The below is my code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("International_Employees.xlsx")
for ws in wb:
    for row in iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if str(cell.value) == 'SALARY':
                salary = "{1}".format(cell.value, cell.offset(0,1).value)
                print(salary)
```

The output is simply: `10000` instead of `£10,000` or `£10000`

How do I tell the program to read the symbol as well using `openpyxl`?

Comment: Could you tell what the `iter_rows()` method does?

Comment: `iter_rows()` iterates through each row in the sheet. I just added a line that I previously missed: `for cell in row` - I'm then iterating through each cell in each row to read my required values from the respective cells.

Comment: *"read the symbol as well"*: As you said: *"symbol was added via the Format Cell"* a Cell format is not part of the Cell value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `number_format` property to find out, here is an example of how you could implement that:

```
c = ws['A1']
fmt = c.number_format
print(fmt) # >>> for me: #,##0.00\ "€"

symbol = re.search(r"[€£]", fmt)
if not symbol:
    print("no currency")
else:
    print(f"{c.value} {symbol.group(0)}") # >>> 1000 €
```

Update:

[image: d]

Update2:

```
for ws in wb:
    for row in iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            print(cell.value, cell.number_format)
```

Comment: I tried using it, but it says: `'str' object has no attribute 'number_format'`

Comment: Because you are not supposed to manipulate a string, but a [cell object](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html). And if I posted this snippet, it is because I tested ijust before and it worked... (see update)

Comment: See the picture I added

Comment: Isn't `c = ws['A1']` from your code an equivalent of my `salary = "{1}".format(cell.value, cell.offset(0,1).value)` ?? If not, then where in my code can I specify the `number_format` attribute?

Comment: `c = ws['A1']` is the way [documentation propose to access to a specific cell](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html). I'll update my answer with an example base on your implementation, if that can help you...

Comment: That would be very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: YES!! It works now. Thanks a lott for the quick update.. But its also shows a weird character `Â` in the output: `"Â£"#,##0.00` - Any idea why this could happen and is there a way to avoid `Â`?

Comment: Glad to help. For the strange car you get, I can't say, since i can not reproduce this problem... however, the regex extraction (`re.search`) will get rid of this. Btw, consider marking the question as solved if the answer helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much once again.