# Python: how to import Excel cell's displayed (formatted) value instead of real value

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

For example, a cell has a real value of `1.96`. The cell is formatted with rounding so that it displays `2` in Excel.
Another example, a cell has a value of `5`, but it is formatted to display currency, so `$5`.
There could be any type of formatting. So I cannot know advance what formatting I am looking for.

How do I import these displayed values with Python? I've looked into Pandas and openpyxl but couldn't find a way.

I can do it semi-manually by creating a custom VBA module. following Duncan O'Donnell's answer (the last one) here: https://superuser.com/questions/678934/how-can-i-get-the-displayed-value-of-a-cell-in-ms-excel-for-text-that-was-conv

But I need to fully automate and do it in Python. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to solve this with VBA... so I guess there is no easy way with Python after all.

Answer (score 2):

Openpyxl has a feature called [number_format](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html) which could come in handy. I basically played with the output of [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) to get to this.

```
 #let's say we have a value in cell C2 which is 1.96 but formatted to 2.0
 print(ws['C2'].number_format)
 
 #   #
```

The # indicates it is formatted as an integer.

```
# Create a conditional:

if fmt=="#":
    r = round(ws['C2'].value)
print(r)

2.0
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it should help with your use case.

For the dollar part, I will refer you to this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56151644/7175713), as I believe it captures your use case quite well.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. 
I've updated my question. The project I'm working on could have any number of random formatting. So I cannot know in advance what kind of formatting I am looking for and catch them like this.

Comment: That's a bit of a hard one. Cant really make a call on this one... but number_format should give u a guide. I believe if you play around with it a bit, you could get some insights.